# Conditional probability of 3 events

Tags: probability

I have this homework assignment and I have problem solving it:

Let be P(A|B∩C) = 0.5, P(B|A∩C) = 0.3, P(C|A∩B) = 0.9

Calculate: P(A∩B∩C | (A∩B)∪(A∩C)∪(B∩C))

I have problem with interpreting P(A|B∩C) is it P(A| (B∩C) ) or is it P(A|B) ∩ P(C)?
And what is solution to this problem?

Comment: "I have problem with interpreting P(A|B∩C) is it P(A| (B∩C) ) or is it P(A|B) ∩ P(C)" This part is easy to answer since P(A|B) ∩ P(C) is meaningless (real number intersecting real number??). (Of course another, more direct, option would be to consult some source on the subject.)

Answer (score 0):

Draw three intersecting circles labelled $A$, $B$ and $C$, i.e. a Venn Diagram, and let the central region i.e. $A \cap B \cap C=x$.

Let the region $A \cap B \cap C'$, i.e. the region common to $A$ and $B$  but excluding $C$, be $y$ and similarly let $A \cap C \cap B'$ be $z$ and $B \cap C \cap A'$ be $w$.

Then according to the information given, $$\frac{x}{x+w}=0.5\Rightarrow x=w$$
$$\frac {x}{x+z}=0.3\Rightarrow z=\frac{7x}{3}$$
$$\frac{x}{x+y}=0.9\Rightarrow y=\frac{x}{9}$$

You need to find $$\frac{x}{x+y+z+w}=\frac{x}{x+\frac x9 +\frac{7x}{3}+x}=\frac {9}{40}$$